# How to use add_action to hook a static method from other Class

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-hook

I tried to use hook to call a static method, but it failed.

I add the action in test.php like this

```
 require_once('class.test.php');
 add_action('register_new_user', array('Test','auto_signin'),20);
```

and my auto_signin function put in class.test.php file:

```
 namespace MyTest;
 echo(12);
 class Test {
    function __construct()
    {

    }

    public static function auto_signin()
    {
       echo('hello');
       die();
    }
  }
```

when I debuged it, the hook register_new_user did execute and from the global variable wp_filters, the auto_signin function had been added to register_new_user, but the function never executed.

Comment: See [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) and examples are provided

Comment: @Haotian Liu could u tell me how should I fix it, I think I just did the same thing as examples did

Comment: I tried this and posted my answer, hope it can help.

Answer (score 8):

Your class, `Test`, is namespaced however you aren't using any namespace when calling `add_action`.

Update this:

```
add_action('register_new_user', array('Test','auto_signin'),20);
```

To this:

```
add_action( 'register_new_user', array( 'MyTest\Test', 'auto_signin' ), 20 );
```

Comment: @Popnoodles I don't believe that would be valid in this context. The question is about using a static method with add_action. If add_action was being called within the class, they'd be able to use ` __CLASS__` but the example provided shows it's from outside.

Comment: ah, from 'other' class. ok

Answer (score 1):

The way you are trying will work when you want to attach object method to hook not the static method of the class. Since you want the static method of the class to attach to a hook, you need to add like below.

```
 add_action('register_new_user', 'Test::auto_signin',20);
```

instead of `add_action('register_new_user', array('Test','auto_signin'),20);`

Note: if you want to hook from another file you need to add namespace too and call code like below

```
add_action('register_new_user', '\MyTest\Test::auto_signin',20);
```

Answer (score 0):

I read [Wordpress Plugin API Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), but I cannot find any action named `register_new_user`, so you must be using a custom hook.

However, the method will be executed if and only if it is hooked and this hook should a corresponding `do_action` hook.

See this code:

```
class PluginTest {
    function __construct(){
    }
    public static function insertNew(){
        echo 'Hi!';
        die();
    }
}

do_action('custom_admin_notices');

add_action( 'custom_admin_notices', array('PluginTest', 'insertNew'), 20);
global $wp_filter;
var_dump($wp_filter['custom_admin_notices']);
```

If the `do_action` line is commented, you can still see the hook in the global variable while the method won't be executed. So check whether the line containing `do_action` is executed.

Comment: if I changed  `add_action('register_new_user', array('Test','auto_signin'),20); ` to  `add_action('register_new_user', function(do something);)` , the function will be executed.